# Copy Dictionary<String, String> to clipboard for Excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, clipboard

I am trying to write a tool which will compare two string tables and find values which are in one but not the other. I have got the app so that it is getting all these values correctly and I store them in a `Dictionary<string, string>` and use that to display it on a GridView in my XAML.

I then found out that you have to manually add the copy code to the GridView so I thought I would just have a button to copy the entire contents of the dictionary, but now I am having a problem that when I try to copy it into excel it only produces one column of values and I need the key to be one column and the value to be another.

Here is my copy code so far:

```
        if (ToTranslate.Count != 0)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in ToTranslate)
            {
                sb.Append(item.Key + ", ");
                sb.AppendLine(item.Value);
            }

            System.Windows.Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, sb.ToString());
        }
```

I have tried lots of other things such as item.string which the puts them in square brackets and still doesn't work. I have also tried trimming the square brackets but this still doesn't work.

I would have thought that it would have picked up the comma as a seperator like it does when you open up a csv but it doesn't.

I don't know if this will help but this is my xaml

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Results}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Text" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" />                        
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Have you tried using tab as separator?

Comment: @Nitram YES, that works, thank you very much. I can't believe I never thought about a tab. Please add that as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel likes the tab character as separator.
To import CSV you need the import assistent of Excel and that thing only opens in case you open a file that contains the CSV data.

Using the tab character is working well how ever.